# Error on generating signed apk duplicate string conflict

Tags: android

I have a App where i have Norwegian from e earlier version of my app and have now update my app but when i try and "Generate Signed Apk" so get i this issue:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

> C:\Dating App\app\src\main\res\values-nb-rNO\strings.xml: Error: Found item String/label_location_prompt more than one time

I have also try and change nb-rNO to: nb-no but still the same.

I have also try and copy "default english strings.xml to folder nb-rNO and try and "Generate Signed Apk" and that working.
But not Norwegian languages file.
Also clean project and it not help me.

Have try and search for it but i have never see this issue so hope someone can help me :)

I use Android Studio 1.5.1

Comment: try to restart the studio.. sometimes works..

Comment: Same issue after restart of studio!

Answer (score 0):

one of your strings (`label_location_prompt`) appears in more than one file and is being duplicated in the merge process.

it's probably referenced in more than one file (such as multiple resource files with string resources or your build.gradle file) search for that in your codebase and remove the one you don't want and it should build without issues

Comment: Hello @thepoosh :)
Thanks for the answer :)
But where can i find "Codebase"? 
So i can remove Norwegian and put it in again.

Comment: try clicking shift-shift and searching

Comment: Still the same.
I try and search after nb-rNO with shift but it not help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android try searching for the string in the whole workspace.Follow the steps
In the menu bar Edit -> Find -> Find in path -> Enter the text to find -> Select scope as whole project -> Hit Find. You will get the list of recurrence of string in whole project

Comment: Yes i use Android Studio 1.5.1.
I have try this now with search name: nb-rNO but then come up:
No occurences of nb-rNO found in project.
I

Comment: search for this string "label_location_prompt"

Comment: Hi Hardik,
Yes i find this text as you say i must try and then i see this:
public static final int label_location_prompt=0x7f08010c; IN R.java and there stay:
Files under the build folder are generated and schould not be edited.
So for me so must i find how i delete the old strings from Norwegian.
I have reinstalled and change folders and all and still same issue.

Comment: i think you should rename label_location_prompt to some thing like lbl_location_prompt and then check whether its working or not...it seems this string also resides in some of the library you are using.So best option is to rename it in your string.xml file

Comment: Hello Hardik,
Where schould i change it?
For there stay in R.java i schould not edit the file.
I have also try and change strings.xml to string.xml but still the same.

Comment: dont change the file name...change the string id from label_location_prompt to something else.

Comment: Hi,
Yes but i only find it in "R.java"

Comment: hmm then it seem it might be conflict between libraries.

Comment: Yes maybe that is the problem.
Have try lot of solution now :)

Comment: can you post values-nb-rNO\strings.xml here?

Comment: Yes i upload it to dropbox so you can see it here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9a0gr4ic8uzdzkk/strings.xml?dl=0

Name is: strings.xml

Comment: label_location_prompt appears twice in this string.xml

Comment: Hmm ok.
Will it be possible to fix it ? :)

Comment: may be...just try it

Comment: What schould i try ? 
And how ? :)

Comment: where can i remove it? Where can i find the duplicate?